# SharePoint copyTo moveTo with document library error

Tags: workflow, document-library, visual-studio, event-handlers, copy

Using event handlers and workflows I am trying to archive a document library after a certain amount of time has passed. However I am having an issue with moving the document library. This is the code I am using to move the library

```
SPFolder folder = (SPFolder) properties.Web.GetFileOrFolderObject(source);
folder.CopyTo(dest);
properties.ListItem["Archived"] = "Archived";
```

I tried to use both copyTo and moveTo but I am getting the same error for both

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: 'Error copying folder "/TestArchive".  You cannot copy a folder that contains lists, surveys, discussion boards, or document libraries.' COMException: 0x8107096eError copying folder "/TestArchive".  You cannot copy a folder that contains lists, surveys, discussion boards, or document libraries.

The library structure looks kind of like this

```
Archive
------OtherArchiveFiles

TestArchive
-----Docs
--------------TextFiles
```

And I am trying to get it to be like this

```
Archive
------OtherArchiveFiles
------TestArchive
--------------Docs
------------------TextFiles
```

Is there a way to fix this error or do I need to individually move the files in `TestArchive` into newly created folders in `Archive`?

EDIT :

So I got it working by individually copying the folders in the doclib to a newly created folder in the `Archived` Library. Here is my code

```
SPFolder folderDest = (SPFolder) properties.Web.GetFileOrFolderObject(dst);
SPFolder folderSrc = (SPFolder)properties.Web.GetFileOrFolderObject(source);
folderDest.SubFolders.Add(dest);
folderDest.Update();
foreach (SPFolder folder in folderSrc.SubFolders) {
       if (!folder.Name.Equals("Forms")) {
           folder.MoveTo(dest + "/" + folder.Name);
           folderDest.Update();
       }

}
properties.ListItem["Archived"] = "Archived";
folderSrc.Delete();
folderDest.Update();
```

However I still want to know if its possible to just move the whole library at once.